# convertir de JSON a dataframe

Tags: python, json, url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy intentando convertir un archivo JSON desde una url, pero el resultado, que debería ser un dataframe, solo tiene una columna.

Utilizo la función:

```
def covid_so ():
  URL ='https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid-19/casedistribution/json/'
  headers={'cch':'ncch'}
  response = requests.request('GET', URL, headers=headers)
  parse =json.loads(response.text)
  df =pd.DataFrame(json.loads(response.text))
  return df
cov_df =covid_so()
cov_df.shape
```

(61900, 1)

Agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: El indentado de tu código es incorrecto. Por ejemplo, ese `return df` seguro debería estar al nivel del resto de la función `covid_so`. Revisa esto primero, edita tu pregunta y ahí sí cuéntanos qué sale con el código correctamente indentado

Comment: He indentado return df y sigue saliendo el mismo resultado. Tarda un poco, pero devuelve el mismo (61900,1)

Comment: Intenté reproducir tu código y obtengo un error 404, ¿podrías compartir directamente el json que obtienes?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Parace ser que la url es `https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/`

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho y ricardo-dic, he intentado subir una captura de pantalla del JSON, pero me veo un poco lento, es la primera vez que entro en stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo, es retornar mediante `requests` el objeto JSON, que no es más que un diccionario, y de ese objeto leer el valor de la clave `records` que es la lista de filas en forma de nuevos diccionarios del tipo `nombre columnas: valor`, este formato es interpretado por `pandas` de forma natural:

```
import pandas as pd  
import requests

def covid_so():
  URL ='https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json'
  resp = requests.get(URL).json()
  return pd.DataFrame(resp['records'])

df = covid_so()
```